# MapStruct mapping on objects of type List

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am trying to use MapStruct for a structure similar to the following:

```
@Data
public class ClassAEntity {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private String numT;
  private List<ClassBEntity) bs;
}

@Data
public class ClassBEntity {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private String numT;
  private List<Other> oc;
}

@Data
public class ClassA {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private List<ClassB) bs;
}

@Data
public class ClassB {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private List<Other> oc;
}
```

In the interface I have added the following mapping:

`ClassAEntity map(ClassA classA, String numT)`

I get a warning because it can't map numT to classBEntity.numT and I can't add it with @Mapping in the following way:

```
@Mapping(source = "numT", target = "bs[].numT")
```

On the other hand I need to ignore the parameter oc of classBEntity because "Other" object contains classAEntity and forms a cyclic object. (because I use oneToMany JPA). I have tried the following:

`@Mapping(target = "bs[].oc", ignore = true)`

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

MapStruct does not support defining nested mappings for collections. You will have to define more explicit methods.

For example to map `numT` into `bs[].numT` and ignore `bs[].oc` you'll need to do something like:

```
@Mapper
public MyMapper {

    default ClassAEntity map(ClassA classA, String numT) {
        return map(classA, numT, numT);
    }
    
    ClassAEntity map(ClassA classA, String numT, @Context String numT);

    @AfterMapping
    default void setNumTOnClassBEntity(@MappingTarget ClassBEntity classB, @Context String numT) {
        classB.setNumT(numT);
    }

    @Mapping(target = "oc", ignore = "true")
    ClassBEntity map(ClassB classB);

}
```